# How to change Vim window moving key combinations?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, window, vimrc

I found this `:help window-move-cursor`, but I tried to call it from the command line and doesn't work. 
Is there a way to change the key mapping for switch windows?

Comment: Here is a similar post that might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021184/how-to-change-vims-default-keyboard-shortcut-for-toggle-windows

Comment: What is this `h:window-move-cursor` that you found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke any normal mode mappings via `:normal!`. The `<C-w>` used by the window movements is a challenge; you need `:execute` to evaluate the `:help key-notation`:

```
:execute "normal! \<C-w>j"`
```

However, there's the special `:wincmd` that simplifies the invocation; the above example becomes

```
:wincmd j
```

---

Now, if you want to change the key mappings, that can be done via `:map`:

```
:nnoremap <F7> <C-w>j
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to the Ingo's answer here is a set of config that allows you to move to other panes using Control and a movement key.

```
nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works, it's an example in the help for the 'normal' command:

```
:exe "normal \<c-w>\<c-w>"
```